# invalidprogramexception cannot be captured by the try catch block

Tags: c#, invalidprogramexception

there,

a piece of code is like this:

```
try
{
   ClassA a = new ClassA();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   ......
}
```

that class A is in another assembly, however, in some environment, that assembly got corrupted, so I expect I will receive the invalidPrgramExecption. However, when the above code is running in w3wp process, it just got crashed without even if I want to catch the base Exception class.

Do you know what's the reason why InvalidProgramException won't be captured? (because of the multi thread environment?) Is there any way that I can handle this exception gracefully without crash?

Thanks!

Comment: An InvalidProgramException indicates that the MSIL or metadata is invalid.  I don't find it surprising that exception handling won't work if the assembly isn't valid MSIL code.

Comment: Why not just replace the corrupted assembly? Do you actually expect this to happen on a regular basis?

Comment: @BJMyers why not surprising? I assume InvalidProgramException is designed to handle this case

Comment: @EJoshuaS I don't have the permission to replace the corrupted assembly. this case is expected but we have to handle this case gracefully without crash